# React-native. Can't get contact list on android

Tags: javascript, react-native

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />` to manifest and then use https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.
and it's not working for me. but another permissions (like location) worked. any ideas?

```
async requestContactsPermission() {
try {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
    {
      title: 'test',
      message: 'message',
      buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
      buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
      buttonPositive: 'OK',
    },
  );
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    console.log('You can use the contacts');
  } else {
    // always denied
    console.log('Contacts permission denied');
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err);
}


async componentWillMount() {
  await requestContactsPermission();
}
```

my permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
```

...

Comment: can you share code where you implemented the permissions.?

Comment: what do you mean by not working? does the permission request not get send at all or does it get send and accepted but still don't have the permission?

Comment: for other permissions (like location) opens popup with request. for contacts permission popup not showing. and the request returns denied